# How to do a general "search bar" search across multiple SQLAlchemy models

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a search bar for my app. Say the user searched for 'John Smith United Kingdom Oxford University' I would like to return the user from the accounts table with `name` 'John Smith', `location` 'United Kingdom' and `education` 'Oxford University'.

Here is a general overview for the search 'John Smith United Kingdom Oxford University':

- Show accounts from the database with `name` 'John Smith', `location` 'United Kingdom' and `education` 'Oxford University'.
- Show accounts with `name` 'John Smith' and `education` 'Oxford University'
- Show accounts with `name` 'John Smith' and `location` 'United Kingdom'
- Show accounts with `name` 'John Smith'

I cannot find any resources specifically for Flask-SQLAlchemy which specify how to do this. I'm aware I would have to use `.like()` though I don't know how to add it to a SQLAlchemy query in Flask. With SQLAlchemy I could do `.where(column.like())` though I cannot in Flask-SQLAlchemy.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So what about `Smith College`, the state of `Georgia`, or a person named `Paul Ireland`?  How is your application supposed to know which tables to query with which pieces of the search string? Do you want to require the user to always use the exact format `N N L L E E` for name, location and education?

Comment: That's part of my question, as there is no set format for the search like you stated I would like to know how to implement it. For example Facebook and a search bar that recognises names, locations and education/work. When the user sets an account there is a fixed choice of locations which make things easier but `name` and `education` not fixed, so a user can include anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `like()` like you use it in `SQLAlchemy`:

```
User.query.filter(User.name.like("%John Smith%")).all()
```

or you can use `contains()`:

```
User.query.filter(User.name.contains('John Smith')).all()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps with the first part of the issue, though I'm still unsure how to select and order the users as in the question.

Comment: @PavSidhu For location you could use a pre-populated drop down list with all relevant countries. For education something similar (maybe with an other field at the end).

Answer (score 0):

Better you should use ilike

```
User.query.filter(User.name.ilike("%John%")).all()
```

Comment: Hello there is problem in your code please fix it there is a typo